# How do I display my footer at the bottom of the page that can be scrolled?

Tags: html, css

I need help displaying my footer at the bottom of a page that requires scrolling. The code used only works on pages that don't require scrolling. Currently the footer displays on the middle of the page. It is supposed to show at the bottom of the page. I have tried doing what websites tell me to do. Websites including:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-keep-your-footer-where-it-belongs-59c6aa05c59c/
https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/#there-is-flexbox
However both websites don't work....

Cheers

Justin

This is my CSS code.

```
html, body {
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    body {
        background-color: #EEE;
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        background-image: url (logo.png);
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    h1, h2, h3 {
        margin: 0;
    }
    
    a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: blue;
    }
    
    #container {
        background-color: white;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        position: relative;
        min-height: 100vh;
    }   
    
    #header {
        background-color: blue;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    
    #content {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right:10px;
        padding-bottom: 2.5rem;
        margin-right:0px;
        min-height: 100vh;
    }
    
    #nav ul {
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    
    #nav .selected {
        font-family: bold;
    }
    
    #nav {
        width: 18%;
        float: left;
    }
    
    #main {
        width: 60%;
        float: right;
    }
    
    .content {
      flex: 1 0 auto;
    }
    
    .footer {
      flex-shrink: 0;
      color:white;
      background-color:black;
    }
```

Below is my HTML code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <?php
        $database = "seriousdiseases";
        $database = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', $database) or die ("Unable to connect to the 
    DB");
    ?>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Ribose-5-phosphate isomerase deficiency</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="container">
                <div id="header">
                    <h1>Ribose-5-phosphate isomerase deficiency</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <div id="nav">
                        <h3>Navigation</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="aboutUs.html">About Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="video.html">Video</a></li>
                            <li><a href="seriousDiseases.html">Serious Diseases</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div id="main">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Disease</th>
                                <th>Symptoms</th>
                            </tr>
                            <?php
                                $result = mysqli_query($database, "select disease, symptom from 
    feature") or die ("Unable to connect to the DB");
                                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                                    print("<tr><td>" . $row[0] . "</td><td>" . $row[1] . "</td> 
    </tr>");
                                }
                                $database->close();
                            ?>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <footer class="footer">
                    Copyright &copy; 2020 CLINIC SCOPE
                </footer>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

footer should not be in the container. If you take it out of there, your problem will be resolved. I recommend using it for other tags. (Header, nav etc.)

Comment: I took it out, and its better but still isn't working.

Comment: I fixed it. Wooohooo! All I needed to do was take the footer out and then add position relative!

Comment: I put your answer as a tick, because it works! And edited it to add the final step!

Comment: My reputation is too low to plus rep your answer... Sowweeee! haha

Comment: No problem if I could help :)